# Tail Recursion Understanding

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I was wondering if anyone could walk me through tail recursion. I have this procedure I made in Racket and I would like a simple explanation on what steps I should take to utilize what I have in the form of tail recursion.

The code in Racket is as follows,

```
;SQUARE LIST FUNCTION
(define (square-list lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) 0]
    [else (map (lambda (i)
                 (* i i)) lst)]))
```

OR better defined as.

```
(define (square-list lst)
  (for-each (lambda (i)
    (printf "Iteration: ~a\n" (* i i)))lst))
```

So I really just want to know:

- How should I approach changing this procedure into a tail-recursive procedure?

Comment: First make a recursive procedure. Then take it from there.

Comment: The lack of a recursive function implied that he/she doesn't really understand how it works, so I went ahead and explained that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your examples are `tail call optimized` in the sense that, an interpreter can look at it and see that in the first case the `cond` is always executed as the last expression of this function call. This means that it does not keep stack. In your second example it can tell that the `for-each` statement will always be executed last.

For didactic purposes, have a look at the function below:

```
(define (square-list ls)
    (if (empty? ls)
      '()
      (let ((first-square (* (car ls) (car ls))))
          (cons first-square (square-list (cdr ls)))))
```

In this function you will calculate the square of the first element. Then the result of the square of the entire list is this square, `cons`'d to the front of a recursive call to the function to do the same for the rest of the list.

The point is that in this case, the interpreter has to **remember the `first-square` value**, then calculate the rest of the squares and finally create a list out of them. The remembering part is what makes a function non-tail recursive.

So it basically boils down to help your interpreter remember as little as possible by building up your output and passing the intermediate resulsts consecutive calls to the function. So how can we do this? Simple, you pass your squared values into the recursive call and make sure the recursive call is the last statement in your function body.

```
(define (square-list ls squares)
    (if (empty? ls)
      squares
      (let ((first-square (* (car ls) (car ls))))
          (square-list (cdr ls) (cons first-square squares)))
```

What we do here is create the output (list of squares) in the call of the function. This means that every recursive call gets a list of already squared values. So in the body we simply take a value of the "unsquared" list and cons the value to the list of squared values.

So calling this function is as simple as:

```
(square-list '(1 2 3) '())
```

In each iteration we will take the first value from the input list, square it and cons it to the output list.

(Note: this will produce the reverse squared list)

**Example in REPL**

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.6 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 128 MB.
> (define (square-list ls squares)
    (if (empty? ls)
      squares
      (let ((first-square (* (car ls) (car ls))))
          (square-list (cdr ls) (cons first-square squares)))))
> (square-list '(1 2 3) '())
'(9 4 1)
>
```

Comment: What does the squares value do in the second square-list?
No matter what gets placed in there it seems to make a dotted list.
The cons at the end means that each square is getting added to squares right? Why must I have a value for squares?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, you need to keep the calculated values (i.e., squares) in a parameter of your function. If not, you have to remember them in your function body. If I execute the function above I get a proper list (in reverse order).